# React router conditionally route or open modal

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

I'm using React Router to handle routing and some views require user to be logged in to be available. I was using react router `Redirect` to handle my views conditionally and that worked fine like so:

```
<Route exact path="/register">
    {cookies.login_status === 'valid' ? <Register /> : <Redirect to="/" />}
</Route>
```

Now however I need to render a view if condition is met or open a modal instead of routing. Right now my Route looks like this:

```
<Route exact path="/register">
    {cookies.login_status === 'valid' ? <Register /> : openModal}
</Route>
```

If the condition is met I load the view component and if not I call function to open the modal. The modal opens just fine but also a blank view is served.

So I guess my question is how can I stop it from routing/redirecting if a condition is not met and simply just open the modal on the current view?

Comment: Why don't add same condition in Register component? If login_status is valid show component code other wise open modal

Comment: I think the problem is that the condition is checked AFTER the new route was entered, so you're URL should be at the new route already and therefore no component will be displayed in the "background"

Answer (score 0):

Why not use a modal props like this and open the modal from Register component?

```
<Route exact path="/register">
    <Register modal={cookies.login_status === 'valid'} />
</Route>
```